# How can I use an array of function pointers?

Tags: c, initialization, function-pointers

How should I use array of function pointers in C?

How can I initialize them?

Answer (score 275):

You have a good example [here (Array of Function pointers)](http://www.java2s.com/Code/C/Function/Arrayoffunctionpointer.htm), with the [syntax detailed](http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html#chapter2).

```
int sum(int a, int b);
int subtract(int a, int b);
int mul(int a, int b);
int div(int a, int b);

int (*p[4]) (int x, int y);

int main(void)
{
  int result;
  int i, j, op;

  p[0] = sum; /* address of sum() */
  p[1] = subtract; /* address of subtract() */
  p[2] = mul; /* address of mul() */
  p[3] = div; /* address of div() */
[...]
```

To call one of those function pointers:

```
result = (*p[op]) (i, j); // op being the index of one of the four functions
```

---

You can also initialize `p` as:

```
int (*p[4]) (int, int) = {sum, subtract, mul, div};
```

As in:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

// Function declarations
int sum(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
int subtract(int a, int b) { return a - b; }
int mul(int a, int b) { return a * b; }
int div(int a, int b) { return (b != 0) ? a / b : 0; }

int main() {
    // Array of function pointers initialization
    int (*p[4]) (int, int) = {sum, subtract, mul, div};

    // Using the function pointers
    int result;
    int i = 20, j = 5, op;

    for (op = 0; op < 4; op++) {
        result = p[op](i, j);
        printf("Result: %d\n", result);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As note by [Gauthier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108802/gauthier) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252748/how-can-i-use-an-array-of-function-pointers/252750#comment119613671_252750)

> You can call functions by a pointer *without* dereferencing it.
>
> Some might argue that they want the dereference to be explicit, so they know what they're dealing with.
> Others would reply that it's a known idiom, and that there isn't much more that `p[op]()` could ever mean.
>
> `result = p[op](i, j);` works

[Daniel Heimgartner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12995716/daniel-heimgartner) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252748/how-can-i-use-an-array-of-function-pointers/252750#comment135296752_252750):

> Initializing the array of pointers `p[0] = sum` and `p[0] = &sum` are equivalent.
> Similarly, when calling a function (via a function pointer) you do not need to dereference `(*)` it: See this Stack Overflow question "[How come a pointer to a function be called without dereferencing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/944479/6309)"

Comment: @crucifiedsoul "the C Programming Language" written by Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie? It could be, but I didn't have it as a reference at the time I wrote the answer three and an half year ago. So I don't know.

Comment: I'd like to add you can initialize p with `(*p[4]) (int, int) {sum,substract,mul,div}`

Comment: @jiggunjer s/substract/subtract/ :p. But thanks for that comment, very useful :). +1.

Comment: @VonC I did not notice this; but yes it really really is; this is absolutely brilliant. Have a corona free year on you! If I could up vote this 1 time more, I would.

Comment: Note that you can call functions by a pointer without dereferencing it. Some might argue that they want the dereference to be explicit, so they know what they're dealing with. Others would reply that it's a known idiom, and that there isn't much more that `p[op]()` could ever mean. `result = p[op](i, j);` works.

Comment: By the way, initializing the array of pointers `p[0] = sum` and `p[0] = &sum` are equivalent. Similarly, when calling a function (via a function pointer) you do not need to dereference (`*`) it... See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944479/how-come-pointer-to-a-function-be-called-without-dereferencing) stackoverflow question.

Comment: @Gauthier Thank you for your feedback. I have edited the answer to include an example and your comment, for more visibility.

Comment: @DanielHeimgartner Thank you for your feedback. I have edited the answer to include an example and your comment, for more visibility.

Answer (score 61):

The above answers may help you but you may also want to know how to use array of function pointers.

```
void fun1()
{

}

void fun2()
{

}

void fun3()
{

}

void (*func_ptr[3])() = {fun1, fun2, fun3};

main()
{
    int option;


    printf("\nEnter function number you want");
    printf("\nYou should not enter other than 0 , 1, 2"); /* because we have only 3 functions */
    scanf("%d",&option);

    if((option>=0)&&(option<=2))
    { 
        (*func_ptr[option])();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can only assign the addresses of functions with the same return type and same argument types and no of arguments to a single function pointer array.

You can also pass arguments like below if all the above functions are having the same number of arguments of same type.

```
  (*func_ptr[option])(argu1);
```

Note: here in the array the numbering of the function pointers will be starting from 0 same as in general arrays. So in above example `fun1` can be called if option=0, `fun2` can be called if option=1 and `fun3` can be called if option=2.

Comment: Even for this little demo, you should add a check for the input value, since code targets a newbie... :-)

Comment: Don't forget #include <stdio.h> at top for newbies like me

Answer (score 11):

Here's how you can use it:

#### New_Fun.h

```
#ifndef NEW_FUN_H_
#define NEW_FUN_H_

#include <stdio.h>

typedef int speed;
speed fun(int x);

enum fp {
    f1, f2, f3, f4, f5
};

void F1();
void F2();
void F3();
void F4();
void F5();
#endif
```

#### New_Fun.c

```
#include "New_Fun.h"

speed fun(int x)
{
    int Vel;
    Vel = x;
    return Vel;
}

void F1()
{
    printf("From F1\n");
}

void F2()
{
    printf("From F2\n");
}

void F3()
{
    printf("From F3\n");
}

void F4()
{
    printf("From F4\n");
}

void F5()
{
    printf("From F5\n");
}
```

#### Main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "New_Fun.h"

int main()
{
    int (*F_P)(int y);
    void (*F_A[5])() = { F1, F2, F3, F4, F5 };    // if it is int the pointer incompatible is bound to happen
    int xyz, i;

    printf("Hello Function Pointer!\n");
    F_P = fun;
    xyz = F_P(5);
    printf("The Value is %d\n", xyz);
    //(*F_A[5]) = { F1, F2, F3, F4, F5 };
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        F_A[i]();
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    F_A[f1]();
    F_A[f2]();
    F_A[f3]();
    F_A[f4]();
    return 0;
}
```

I hope this helps in understanding `Function Pointer.`

Comment: Line 15 of Main.c should be for (i = 0; i < 5; i++), right?

Comment: Why did you declare the fp enumerator?

Comment: @Arrrow: I think I saw some of the legacy code where they made it in that way... And it looks very beautiful. Just remove `f1, f2 ...` and in place of then enter 'writefile, readfromfile...'... it becomes more redable

Answer (score 9):

This "answer" is more of an addendum to VonC's answer; just noting that the syntax can be simplified via a typedef, and aggregate initialization can be used:

```
typedef int FUNC(int, int);

FUNC sum, subtract, mul, div;
FUNC *p[4] = { sum, subtract, mul, div };

int main(void)
{
    int result;
    int i = 2, j = 3, op = 2;  // 2: mul

    result = p[op](i, j);   // = 6
}

// maybe even in another file
int sum(int a, int b) { return a+b; }
int subtract(int a, int b) { return a-b; }
int mul(int a, int b) { return a*b; }
int div(int a, int b) { return a/b; }
```

Comment: Please reserve all caps to pre-processor macros. Many would also advocate created type to end with `_t`, although this seems controversial for user defined types.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simpler example of how to do it:

**jump_table.c**

```cpp
int func1(int arg)  { return arg + 1; }
int func2(int arg)  { return arg + 2; }
int func3(int arg)  { return arg + 3; }
int func4(int arg)  { return arg + 4; }
int func5(int arg)  { return arg + 5; }
int func6(int arg)  { return arg + 6; }
int func7(int arg)  { return arg + 7; }
int func8(int arg)  { return arg + 8; }
int func9(int arg)  { return arg + 9; }
int func10(int arg) { return arg + 10; }

int (*jump_table[10])(int) = { func1, func2, func3, func4, func5, 
                               func6, func7, func8, func9, func10 };
    
int main(void) {
  int index = 2;
  int argument = 42;
  int result = (*jump_table[index])(argument);
  // result is 45
}
```

All functions stored in the array must have the same signature.  This simply means that they must return the same type (e.g. `int`) and have the same arguments (a single `int` in the example above).

---

In C++, you can do the same with *static* class methods (but not instance methods).  For example you could use `MyClass::myStaticMethod` in the array above but not `MyClass::myInstanceMethod` nor `instance.myInstanceMethod`:

```cpp
class MyClass {
public:
  static int myStaticMethod(int foo)   { return foo + 17; }
  int        myInstanceMethod(int bar) { return bar + 17; }
}

MyClass instance;
```

Answer (score 2):

Oh, there are tons of example. Just have a look at anything within glib or gtk.
You can see the  work of function pointers in work there all the way.

Here e.g the initialization of the gtk_button stuff.

```
static void
gtk_button_class_init (GtkButtonClass *klass)
{
  GObjectClass *gobject_class;
  GtkObjectClass *object_class;
  GtkWidgetClass *widget_class;
  GtkContainerClass *container_class;

  gobject_class = G_OBJECT_CLASS (klass);
  object_class = (GtkObjectClass*) klass;
  widget_class = (GtkWidgetClass*) klass;
  container_class = (GtkContainerClass*) klass;

  gobject_class->constructor = gtk_button_constructor;
  gobject_class->set_property = gtk_button_set_property;
  gobject_class->get_property = gtk_button_get_property;
```

And in gtkobject.h you find the following  declarations:

```
struct _GtkObjectClass
{
  GInitiallyUnownedClass parent_class;

  /* Non overridable class methods to set and get per class arguments */
  void (*set_arg) (GtkObject *object,
           GtkArg    *arg,
           guint      arg_id);
  void (*get_arg) (GtkObject *object,
           GtkArg    *arg,
           guint      arg_id);

  /* Default signal handler for the ::destroy signal, which is
   *  invoked to request that references to the widget be dropped.
   *  If an object class overrides destroy() in order to perform class
   *  specific destruction then it must still invoke its superclass'
   *  implementation of the method after it is finished with its
   *  own cleanup. (See gtk_widget_real_destroy() for an example of
   *  how to do this).
   */
  void (*destroy)  (GtkObject *object);
};
```

The (*set_arg) stuff is a pointer to function and this can e.g be assigned another implementation in some derived class.

Often you see something like this

```
struct function_table {
   char *name;
   void (*some_fun)(int arg1, double arg2);
};

void function1(int  arg1, double arg2)....


struct function_table my_table [] = {
    {"function1", function1},
...
```

So you can reach into the table by name and call the "associated" function.

Or maybe you use a hash table in which you put the function and call it "by name".

Regards

Friedrich

Comment: Would it be pssible to use such a function_table for hashing functions within the hash table implementation itself?

(Read: circular dependecy involved).

Answer (score 2):

Can use it in the way like this:

```
//! Define:
#define F_NUM 3
int (*pFunctions[F_NUM])(void * arg);

//! Initialise:
int someFunction(void * arg) {
    int a= *((int*)arg);
    return a*a;
}

pFunctions[0]= someFunction;

//! Use:
int someMethod(int idx, void * arg, int * result) {
    int done= 0;
    if (idx < F_NUM && pFunctions[idx] != NULL) {
        *result= pFunctions[idx](arg);
        done= 1;
    }
    return done;
}

int x= 2;
int z= 0;
someMethod(0, (void*)&x, &z);
assert(z == 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be a short & simple copy & paste piece of code example of the above responses. Hopefully this helps.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define DBG_PRINT(x) do { std::printf("Line:%-4d" "  %15s = %-10d\n", __LINE__, #x, x); } while(0);

void F0(){ printf("Print F%d\n", 0); }
void F1(){ printf("Print F%d\n", 1); }
void F2(){ printf("Print F%d\n", 2); }
void F3(){ printf("Print F%d\n", 3); }
void F4(){ printf("Print F%d\n", 4); }
void (*fArrVoid[N_FUNC])() = {F0, F1, F2, F3, F4};

int Sum(int a, int b){ return(a+b); }
int Sub(int a, int b){ return(a-b); }
int Mul(int a, int b){ return(a*b); }
int Div(int a, int b){ return(a/b); }
int (*fArrArgs[4])(int a, int b) = {Sum, Sub, Mul, Div};

int main(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)  (*fArrVoid[i])();
    printf("\n");

    DBG_PRINT((*fArrArgs[0])(3,2))
    DBG_PRINT((*fArrArgs[1])(3,2))
    DBG_PRINT((*fArrArgs[2])(3,2))
    DBG_PRINT((*fArrArgs[3])(3,2))

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: If it is a copy&paste from other anwers, I'm not sure it adds any value...

Comment: Yes I see your point, I will add the value tonight currently at work.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to give the address of the final vector you want , and modify it inside the function.

```
void calculation(double result[] ){  //do the calculation on result

   result[0] = 10+5;
   result[1] = 10 +6;
   .....
}

int main(){

    double result[10] = {0}; //this is the vector of the results

    calculation(result);  //this will modify result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has been already answered with very good examples. The only example that might be missing is one where the functions return pointers. I wrote another example with this, and added lots of comments, in case someone finds it helpful:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * func1(char *a) {
    *a = 'b';
    return a;
}

char * func2(char *a) {
    *a = 'c';
    return a;
}

int main() {
    char a = 'a';
    /* declare array of function pointers
     * the function pointer types are char * name(char *)
     * A pointer to this type of function would be just
     * put * before name, and parenthesis around *name:
     *   char * (*name)(char *)
     * An array of these pointers is the same with [x]
     */
    char * (*functions[2])(char *) = {func1, func2};
    printf("%c, ", a);
    /* the functions return a pointer, so I need to deference pointer
     * Thats why the * in front of the parenthesis (in case it confused you)
     */
    printf("%c, ", *(*functions[0])(&a)); 
    printf("%c\n", *(*functions[1])(&a));

    a = 'a';
    /* creating 'name' for a function pointer type
     * funcp is equivalent to type char *(*funcname)(char *)
     */
    typedef char *(*funcp)(char *);
    /* Now the declaration of the array of function pointers
     * becomes easier
     */
    funcp functions2[2] = {func1, func2};

    printf("%c, ", a);
    printf("%c, ", *(*functions2[0])(&a));
    printf("%c\n", *(*functions2[1])(&a));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple example for multidimensional array with function pointers":

```
void one( int a, int b){    printf(" \n[ ONE ]  a =  %d   b = %d",a,b);}
void two( int a, int b){    printf(" \n[ TWO ]  a =  %d   b = %d",a,b);}
void three( int a, int b){    printf("\n [ THREE ]  a =  %d   b = %d",a,b);}
void four( int a, int b){    printf(" \n[ FOUR ]  a =  %d   b = %d",a,b);}
void five( int a, int b){    printf(" \n [ FIVE ]  a =  %d   b = %d",a,b);}
void(*p[2][2])(int,int)   ;
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    printf("multidimensional array with function pointers\n");

    p[0][0] = one;    p[0][1] = two;    p[1][0] = three;    p[1][1] = four;
    for (  i  = 1 ; i >=0; i--)
        for (  j  = 0 ; j <2; j++)
            (*p[i][j])( (i, i*j);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the sample code for invoking functions with different signatures with array of pointers.

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define TOTAL_FUNCTIONS 3

#define FUNCTION_ADD 0
#define FUNCTION_SUBTRACT 1
#define FUNCTION_MULTIPLY 2

int funcAdd(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return a+b+c;
}

void funcSubtract(int a, int b)
{
    printf("\nDiffrence = %d\n",a*b);
}

int funcMultiply(int a, int b)
{
    return a*b;
}


int main()
{
    void* funPtr[3] = {funcAdd, funcSubtract, funcMultiply};

    int result = 0;
    int index = 0;
    while(index < TOTAL_FUNCTIONS){
        switch(index){
            case FUNCTION_ADD:
                result = ((int (*)(int, int, int))funPtr[FUNCTION_ADD])(2,3,4);
                printf("\nSum = %d\n", result);
                break;
            case FUNCTION_SUBTRACT:
                ((void (*)(int, int))funPtr[FUNCTION_SUBTRACT])(5,3);
                break;
            case FUNCTION_MULTIPLY:
                result = ((int (*)(int, int))funPtr[FUNCTION_MULTIPLY])(2,3);
                printf("\nProduct %d\n", result);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        ++index;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This solution has undefined behavior. C distinguishes between object pointers and function pointers (`void *` is an object pointer), and C does not allow conversion between them. If you turn compiler diagnostics up to `-pedantic` level you should see warnings. Such conversion is allowed as a common _extension_, but not Standard C. But C _does_ allow conversion between function pointers, so instead of an array of `void *` you could do something like `typedef void (GenFunc)(void); /* ... */ GenFunc *funPtr[3] = { (GenFunc *)funcAdd, /* ... */ };`.

Answer (score -2):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
    
int sum (int , int);
int prod (int , int);
    
int main()
{
    int (*p[2])(int , int ) = {sum,prod};
    
    cout << (*p[0])(2,3) << endl;
    cout << (*p[1])(2,3) << endl;
}
    
int sum (int a , int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
    
int prod (int a, int b)
{
    return a*b;
}
```

Comment: The question is asking about C, not about C++. Please, do not provide C++ answers to C questions. Consider answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5093090/4990392) instead if you think that your answers improves on the existing answers.