# What's the difference between fun(...) and (*fun)(...) using a function pointer in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How come pointer to a function be called without dereferencing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944479/how-come-pointer-to-a-function-be-called-without-dereferencing)
>   [How does dereferencing of a function pointer happen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795575/how-does-dereferencing-of-a-function-pointer-happen)

Supposing I have a function pointer like:

```
void fun() { /* ... */ };
typedef void (* func_t)();
func_t fp = fun;
```

Then I can invoke it by:

```
fp();
```

or

```
(*fp)();
```

What is the difference/

Answer (score 7):

Precisely two parentheses and an asterisk.

Both call the function pointed to by `fun`, and both do so in the same manner.

However, visually, `(*fun)` makes it clear that `fun` is not a function in and of itself, and the dereference operator is a visual cue that it is a pointer of some kind.

The without-parentheses syntax, `fun()`, is the same as a regular function call and so visually equates to that, making it primarily clear you're calling some kind of function. It takes context or a lookup to notice that it is a function pointer.

This is just a style difference, as far as what happens.

Comment: It should also be noted that `(fun)()` and `(**fun)()` are also both legal equivalents.

Comment: +1 for the first line. It was almost exactly the answer I was going to give, except I figured I'd say "one is ugly and the other isn't". :-)