# What's the syntax for declaring an array of function pointers without using a separate typedef?

Tags: c++, arrays, syntax, function-pointers, typedef

Arrays of function pointers can be created like so:

```
typedef void(*FunctionPointer)();
FunctionPointer functionPointers[] = {/* Stuff here */};
```

What is the syntax for creating a function pointer array without using the `typedef`?

Comment: Interesting question, but in "real" code you should just follow the golden rule of function pointers: use `typedef` otherwise no one will be able to understand your code. `:)`

Answer (score 128, accepted):

```
arr    //arr 
arr [] //is an array (so index it)
* arr [] //of pointers (so dereference them)
(* arr [])() //to functions taking nothing (so call them with ())
void (* arr [])() //returning void
```

so your answer is

```
void (* arr [])() = {};
```

But naturally, this is a bad practice, just use `typedefs` :)

***Extra:***
Wonder how to declare an array of 3 pointers to functions taking int and returning a pointer to an array of 4 pointers to functions taking double and returning char? (how cool is that, huh? :))

```
arr //arr
arr [3] //is an array of 3 (index it)
* arr [3] //pointers
(* arr [3])(int) //to functions taking int (call it) and
*(* arr [3])(int) //returning a pointer (dereference it)
(*(* arr [3])(int))[4] //to an array of 4
*(*(* arr [3])(int))[4] //pointers
(*(*(* arr [3])(int))[4])(double) //to functions taking double and
char  (*(*(* arr [3])(int))[4])(double) //returning char
```

:))

Answer (score 16):

Remember "delcaration mimics use". So to use said array you'd say

```
 (*FunctionPointers[0])();
```

Correct? Therefore to declare it, you use the same:

```
 void (*FunctionPointers[])() = { ... };
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
void (*FunctionPointers[])() = { };
```

Works like everything else, you place [] after the name.

Answer (score 0):

I've been building a game engine and have found that I needed dynamically allocated arrays of function pointers.

To address this simply, I've opted for encapsulating the function pointers inside a class.

Here's a simple example:

```
class Function{
    private:

    public:
        int (*sampleFunction)(int);
};

static int returnInt(int val){
    int ret = 20 * i;
    return ret;
}

int main(void){
    Function *functions;   /* V put yours here V */
    size_t functionCount =    getFunctionCount();
    
    functions = new Function[functionCount];
    
    for(int i=0; i<functionCount; i++)
        functions[i].sampleFunction = &returnInt;

    for(int i=0; i<functionCount; i++)
        functions[i].sampleFunction(i);

    return 0;
}
```

Where can this be useful?

Say that you have a graphical application that you're building that creates buttons out of an undefined number of files in a directory.

Each button has a unique "hitbox" coordinate relative to it's position in an array, and you need to be able to uniquely handle a mouse click for each button.

The Functions class is meant to be placed inside another, more complex, class. Where the point of the function pointer is to make it easier to redefine the button click event when different algorithms are required for the same "form element".