# C - Array of pointers to functions of pointers to functions returning strings

Tags: c, pointers

I've discovered function pointers in C recently and I'm trying to get it working fine but I'm just pulling my hair on this!!!

I have a pointer to a function returning a string:

```
(char *) (*)() (*bar)().
```

But I want an array of 6 pointers to function on this but I can't get it working.

I keep getting compiler errors probably with parentheses stuff it's really messy. I've tried something like this but doesn't work:

```
(((char)(*))((*))(((*)((foo))))([(6)]));
```

I need help to do this array am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What do you mean **you have discovered...**?

Comment: Can you clarify "*I want an array of 6 pointers to function on this*" ?

Comment: char*(*fun[6])(void)?  Your original "pointer to function returning a string" is wrong already

Comment: Try use typedef to simplify your types.

Comment: @parag,  the OP is obviously on a very early stage of learning. I do not think the scorn was necessary, esp when you have hardly helped the guy in anyway. This is sheer trolling IMHO.

Comment: [How to use array of function pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/252748/777186)

Comment: For the people like @Krishnabhadra who dont respect beginners like me i will say: you should be ashamed you have been beginner once too no need to be that arrogant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you define a pointer to a function which return a string :

```
(char *) (*myFuncPtr)() = myFunc
```

Array :

```
(char *) (*myFuncPtr[6])();

myFuncPtr[0] = myFunc
```

etc...

Comment: Thank you for the help i tested it it works good!!! People like @Krishnabhadra dont even respect that some people can be beginners if people on this site are so arrogant as him i wont want to participate here :(

Answer (score 1):

Follow [giorashc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10276347/1139697) or use a simple `typedef`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef const char * (*szFunction)();

const char * hello(){ return "Hello";}
const char * world(){ return "world";}
const char * test(){ return "test";}
const char * demo(){ return "demo";}
const char * newline(){ return "\n";}
const char * smiley(){ return ":)";}

int main()
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    szFunction myFunctions[6];
    myFunctions[0] = hello;
    myFunctions[1] = world;
    myFunctions[2] = test;
    myFunctions[3] = demo;
    myFunctions[4] = newline;
    myFunctions[5] = smiley;

    for(i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
        printf("%s\n",myFunctions[i]());
    return 0;
}
```

[**Ideone demo**](http://ideone.com/Xbnmm)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like your initial example is valid. To define a function pointer `f` that return a pointer to a character array, you should use the following syntax.

```
char* (*f)() = &func1
```

If you want an array of function pointers, use the syntax below

```
char* (*arrf[6])() = { &func1, &func2, &func3, &func4, &func5, &func6 }
```

Here's also a link to a [useful old course handout](http://ieng6.ucsd.edu/~cs12x/declare.txt) on function pointers.