# What about functions pointer list?

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to use array of function pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252748/how-to-use-array-of-function-pointers)

I am wondering how one can declare in C a **dynamic** list of function pointers ? Using a pointer to function pointer ?

Comment: Note that http://cdecl.org/ is really useful for these things: searching "array 5 of pointer to function (int, float, double) returning int" gives you an example of a static list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pointer to a function pointer, with which you can use to point to a block of dynamically allocated memory. Let's say the function type is `void (int)`:

```
void (*(*))(int) // Bare type
void (*(*f))(int) // Variable
```

Or you may want an array to function pointers, in which case:

```
void (*[10])(int) // Bare type
void (*af[10])(int) // Variable
```

You can change the parameter and the return type of the functions.

An array of function pointers can be used as a map from number to function to be executed. It is one way to do emulation - for example, after you have obtained the OP code from the instruction, you can execute the operation by using the array of pointer. (This is one way to do so, but I'm not sure whether it is actually done in emulation code).

Comment: in your first piece of code void *(*)(int) how to add my list variable name ?

Comment: Edited to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks, but how now should I call the function using the pointer to a function pointer ?

Comment: Your first code is a pointer to a function that returns a pointer. Not a pointer to a pointer to a function that returns void. Your second code is a pointer to an array of functions, which is illegal.

Comment: @newacct: Fixed. Wanted to bomb the answer, but I fix it anyway since it is accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can have an array of function pointers.

This might be useful, for instance for collecting a set of callback functions for a specific event.

As an example, consider implementing `addEventListener` to DOM elements in a browser, where any DOM element can have multiple `click` events. A simple data structure might be:

```
void (*clickHandlers[MAX_EVENT_HANDLERS])(EventData arg);
```

For a *dynamic* list then allocate a buffer of function pointers using `malloc`, and `realloc` as you need more space:

```
void (**clickHandlers)(EventData arg);
```

Comment: Yes but my question is how to declare this "buffer of function pointers"

Comment: The second one is wrong. It is a pointer to a function that returns a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

For a dynamic list, you can use a basic linked list:

```
struct list {
   int (*func)(int, float, double);
   struct list *next;
}
```

Or an array of function pointers which is resized as necessary.