# Function in another function

Tags: c++, function-pointers

If we have two function e.g A and B. And we call function B in the function A. Is it necessary to define function B before defining function A?

Comment: Why don't you just try it? It's faster.

Answer (score 7):

No, you can declare the functions and define them afterwards.

```
//declarations
void foo();
void goo();

//definitions
void foo() { goo(); }
void goo() { foo(); }

//...
foo(); //stackoverflow, but hey, it compiles
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no such dependency. You can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252748/using-an-array-of-function-pointers/10700827#10700827).

Particularly, in case of `DLL` when we are using function pointers. we need to store the address of the function at `runtime` only after library gets loaded (`LoadLibrary()`).

Answer (score 0):

**Function declarations**

```
void B();
void A();
```

**Function definitions**

```
void B() 
{ 
    A(); 
}
void A() 
{ 
    B(); 
}

//...
A();
```

I hope your question will be clear by this code.

you can implement in this manner.