# Array of function pointer

Tags: c

Is it possible to replace all of these "if, else if ..." with an array of function pointers in this example of code ?

```
  if (strncmp(buff, "ls\n", 3) == 0)
    my_ls();
  else if (strncmp(buff, "cd\n", 3) == 0)
    my_cd();
  else if (strncmp(buff, "user\n", 5) == 0)
    my_user();
  else if (strncmp(buff, "pwd\n", 4) == 0)
    my_pwd();
  else if (strncmp(buff, "quit\n", 5) == 0)
    my_quit();
```

I'm trying to get something like this :

```
void (*tab[5]) (void);

  tab[0] = &my_ls;
  tab[1] = &my_cd;
  tab[2] = &my_user;
  tab[3] = &my_pwd;
  tab[4] = &my_quit;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use an array of function pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252748/how-can-i-use-an-array-of-function-pointers)

Comment: You don't need the reference before function name.

Comment: @cerkiewny Not a duplicate, since this question is really an associative array problem in disguise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a code to illustrate what you wanted to do, because I it's pretty entertaining.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// your functions
void my_ls()  { puts("fun:my_ls")  ;}
void my_cd()  { puts("fun:my_cd")  ;}
void my_user(){ puts("fun:my_user");}
void my_pwd() { puts("fun:my_pwd") ;}
void my_quit(){ puts("fun:my_quit");}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char* buff="ls\n"; // the string you have to compare

    void (*tab[5]) (void)={my_ls,my_cd,my_user,my_pwd,my_quit};
    char *names[5]={"ls\n","cd\n","user\n","pwd\n","quit\n"};

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        if(strncmp(buff,names[i],strlen(names[i]) )==0){
            tab[i]();
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There are other ways to write it. Actually `my_function` is the same as `&my_function` since a function name alone is converted to the adress of the function.
Also `tab[i]()` is equivalent to `(*tab[i])()`... Those are weird behaviours but I think it's specified by C standard

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem with an array of function pointers, but you'd need to convert the sequence of boolean strncmp() results to a single index.

If the list is long, the hash table idea might be a winner.  For compact, simple code and easy maintenance, I've used an array of structs:

```
typedef struct cmdtable_t
{
    void (*fptr)();
    unsigned char length
    char name[11];
} cmdtable_t, *pcmdtable_t;

cmd_table_t commands = {
    { my_ls,   2, "ls"},
    { my_cd,   2, "cd" },
    { my_user, 4, "user" },
    ...etc.
};
```

That could also be what a hash table entry looks like, could be sorted in advance to allow a binary search, or simply sequentially searched for a KISS version until you find out whether this needs optimizing at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a dictionary or [hashtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table):

- Use `buff` as string key
- Use function pointer as values

Comment: hash table or dictionary will be slower then known offset function call. But it will be much faster the individual strncmp.