# How to input function to run when you have many options

Tags: c, if-statement, input, switch-statement

First lets say you have functions

```
void foo1 (...)
{...}
void foo2 (...)
{...}
void foo3 (...)
{...}
void foo4 (...)
{...}
void foo5 (...)
{...}
```

Now I know we can pick a function by using either of these

```
void pickFunction1(char input[])
{
    if (strcmp(input, "foo1") == 0) foo1(...);
    else if (strcmp(input, "foo2") == 0) foo2(...);
    else if (strcmp(input, "foo3") == 0) foo3(...);
    else if (strcmp(input, "foo4") == 0) foo4(...);
    else if (strcmp(input, "foo5") == 0) foo5(...);
}

void pickFunction2(char input[])
{
    switch(input) {
        case 'foo1' :
            foo1(... );
            break;
        case 'foo2' :
            foo2(... );
            break;
        case 'foo3' :
            foo3(... );
            break;
        case 'foo4' :
            foo4(... );
            break;
        case 'foo5' :
            foo5(... );
            break;
}
```

Now my question is what happens when you have many more options, lets say you have `foo1(), foo2(),....foo10000()` then the previous two `pickFunction`s will grow linearly (O(N) where N is the number of options) with the amount of options available.  Is there a way to make this linear growth of function selection into to a more constant growth function selection?  Like something akin to `(funcall input)`in LISP?

Comment: "what happens when you have many more options, lets say you have foo1(), foo2(),....foo10000()" ... umm... you ... quit your job ....

Comment: refer this page for better understanding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252748/how-can-i-use-an-array-of-function-pointers

Comment: @krpra,  eh, so that was the term, I didn't know.  However doesn't that only work for functions with the same type and amount of parameters?

Comment: Don't forget the calling only occurs once so you have the same parameters going in so yes the functions should strictly have the same prototype.  C being what it is, you might be able to bodge some kind of subset where some of the functions have the same starting prototype but fewer actual parameters (e.g. parameters 1 & 2 are the same but some are missing 3 & 4) and cast them as you initialise the array.  Only CDECL will work in this way though I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `array of function pointer` it's an array where each cells of the array is stored the adress of the function. You can fill it in a loop, same for the usage.

Comment: in this way can you only fill the cells with the functions?  or are you also able to add the parameters to the cell?

Comment: You fill the cells with function name and when you call the cells which points to the function, you add the parameters.

example found on stackoverflow : 

`int sum(int a, int b);


int (*p[1]) (int x, int y);


int main(void)
{
  int result;

  p[0] = sum;`

And when you call it :

`result = (*p[0]) (3, 4);`

Comment: @FelipeSantana If you're adding the parameters at compile time then are you talking about a constant?  If so, you might want an array of structures holding the function and any known parameters.  You can build your call from that.

Comment: Sorry for the syntax, it doesn't look good visualy.. `sum` is the function that do `a + b`

Comment: @LoztInSpace so array of function pointers but instead of functions let them be structures?

Comment: Array of structures, one member of which is the function pointer, the other members are known parameter values

Comment: Minimum members are the string to identify the function from the input and the function pointer.