# C - Function Pointer Array - How to call function from array depending on opcode

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, opcode

Hello StackOverflow Community,

How do I call a function from a function pointer array based on the passed opcode?

For example when I read the opcode '0x1A' and pass it to a function pointer array I want to call some function for example 'add()'.

How can I do that without using switch/case ?

My function pointer array:

```
void (*execOp[4])(int opcode) = { add, sub, div, mul };
```

My Codebase:

```
const int memory[2]= {0x1A, 0x1D}; // Memory
int pc=0; //Program counter
int opcode; //Current opcode

//Functions
void fetch()
{
  opcode=memory[pc];
}  

void add()
{
  printf("add");
}


int main()
{
  //Decoding Opcodes from Memory
  for(;;)
  {
    fetch();
  }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `switch/case`? Alternatively you can let the opcode to index the array, but it might result in an oversized array.

Comment: Map the opcodes [0x1A, 0x1D, ...] into array indices [0, 1, ...] in a function. Store pointers to the functions in a corresponding array, and invoke the function pointer using something like (*funcptr[index])().

Comment: @EugeneSh.
As far as I know switch/case evaluation is slower than using a function pointer array.
Also another problem is to index the array because then I would have an oversized array as you have mentioned.

Comment: If you can't come up with some straight-forward mapping opcode->index, then you will have to face the trade-off.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252748/how-can-i-use-an-array-of-function-pointers.

Comment: Do all relevant functions have the same signature (i.e. same number/type of parameters and return type)?  If so, you can use a function pointer array.  If not, you'll have to use a `switch` statement.

Comment: Where is your function pointer array?  The notation I'd use is `(*array[index])(arg1, ...);` but you could probably get away with `array[index](arg1, ...);` (where the three dots represent sundry extra arguments, not an actual ellipsis in the code).

Comment: @dbush Yes all relevant functions have the same signature.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler my function pointer array: `void (*execOp[4])(int opcode) { add, sub, div, mul };` the problem is how to filter which function to call for example by passing '0x1A' to call 'add()'.

Comment: Unbalanced braces in `main()`

Comment: What are your possible opcodes?

Comment: @M.Hisoka, it would be appropriate to add that array definition to your question, but note that it is not consistent with the `add()` function you actually present.  It would be much more helpful to present a bona fide [mcve].

Comment: What's the possible range of opcodes?  If it's not too big, create an array whose size is the largest opcode, put the relevant functions in the correct places, and set the rest to `NULL`.

Comment: Are you using C99?  If so, you can use designated initializers to place the opcodes correctly in the array: `void (*execOp[])(int opcode)) = { [OP_ADD] = add, [OP_SUB] = sub, [OP_MUL] = mul, [OP_DIV] = div, ... };` which automatically places things in the right place.  You can then use `if (execOp[opcode] != 0) (*execOp[opCode])(arg);` to call it.  You decide what to do if the pointer is null.  Error?  Terminate?

Comment: @EugeneSh. is currently unspecified, I am looking for a general solution.

Comment: @dbush That's an option but I am searching for an another way because this would be too memory consuming.

Comment: There is no general solution that fits all.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that sounds nice I will try it.